# Convert JSON response to javascript array for POST request

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, json, post

I want to convert this type of JSON response to JavaScript array

Below, there is response I have got using **POST** request

```
[{"ContactID":214},{"ContactID":213},{"ContactID":259},{"ContactID":280}]
```

Comment: `var array = JSON.parse(json)`, surely?

Comment: do you want to access those data?

Answer (score 1):

use

```
dataType:'json'
```

example

```
$.ajax({
  url: "script.php",
  type: "POST",
  data: {id : menuId},
  dataType: "json"
  success: function(data){
  }
});
```

then you don't need `JSON.parse` , you can directly access the response data.

if you want to loop through all values , you can use

```
  success: function(data){
      $.each(data, function (key, value) {
         for(index in value)
         {
           alert(index);
           alert(value[index]);
         }
     });
  }
```